# Online solution for team emergency interventions management

Tags: web-apps, project-management, time-management

I am in charge of a health service composed of **50** rescuers performing sanitary guards. In order to ease the team management and allow a more flexible planning I am looking for an **online** solution with the following requirements:

- one rescuer one account
- guards availability planning
- moderation rights

And these *optional* features:

- guards and rescuers informations (status, visibility, other datas)
- CSV exportation
- online convocations
- others modules such as news, contacts, etc.

I am currently using an almost finished specific web "backoffice" but I do not have the time to make it reliable and entirely functional. Free is not required.

Comment: For context, could you provide a little more information about sanitary guards? What does that work entail? This info should help us navigate the optional features you mentioned.

Comment: Sanitary guards are for instance: I need 3 rescuers between 6am. and 20pm. next Saturday, the rescuers would then indicate their availability and I would finally select the ones chosen and inform them. Not all rescuers have the same level and some guards require specific levels.